# PHP Login & MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm having some trouble with my login feature. I've been searching for hours and I could'nt find any problem. I hope you guys will help me.
I want to get users' login and check if it exists in my DB. Problem is it keeps returning me  : "Password was probably incorrect!". 
I tried an "echo ($count)", it doesn't return anything. Same thing for "echo($result)".

I'm pretty lost right, I can't understand why this doesn't work...

PS : I'm french so you might see some french words.

Here's my login form :

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Applications</title>
    <!--Chargement des feuilles de style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styleLogin.css" />
    <script src="./js/login/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">


        <header></header>

        <section class="main">
            <form class="form-2" id="loginForm" action="./controller/checkLogin.php" method="post">
                <h1><span class="log-in">Se connecter</span></h1>
                <p class="float">
                    <label for="loginLabel"><i class="icon-user"></i>Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                    <input type="text" name="login" id="login">
                </p>
                <p class="float">
                    <label for="passwordLabel"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Mot de passe</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="showpassword" id="password">
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">    
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Se connecter">
                    <input type="button" name="submitVisit" value="Accès utilisateur">
                </p>
            </form>​​
        </section>

    </div>
</body>
```

And here's my checkLogin.php :

```
<?php

session_start();

try {           
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stage','root','');
  }
  catch (Exception $e){ //en cas d'erreur de connexion, afficher le message           
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // username and password sent from form 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $qry = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = 'admin'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);


    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 0){
        die("Password was probably incorrect!");
    }
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    elseif($count == 1){

        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        header("location: ./login_success.php");
    }

    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}

mysql_close($bdd);
?>
```

---

I want to log in with this couple : admin/admin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why are you using PDO then mysql_*???

Comment: confusing :S where is mysql_select_db,why mixing PDO with mysql and moreover mysql_query is deprecated!!

Comment: OMG you code is kind of mess .. you are using mysql_* with pdo and login without using id and password and login each user on submit without even validating input ..

Comment: I'm new to this, please keep it in mind...

Thank you vimalnath, I'll work on it.

Comment: @respondents - Please take note he's new? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your script.

First off, you start by using PDO to connect to the database, then you use `mysql_*` functions (which are deprecated, stick to PDO !!!). Plus, you are not properly escaping your data, and your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection.

Secondly, the query you are using is ... not good.

```
// this is not checking for either the user input data !!!
$qry = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = 'admin'";
```

Your verification code should be something like this:

```
$ps = $bdd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE login = :login AND pass = :password");
$params = array("login" => $_POST['login'], "password" => $_POST['password']);
$ps->execute($params);

$status = (bool) $ps->fetchColumn(0);

if ($status) {
    // login successful
} else {
    // login failed
}
```

**Read up on [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)** (they automatically escape your data, so you don't have to).

**Note:**

If you don't use prepared statements in future code, remember to always escape input from users and pretty much any other source of information.

Comment: No.  `AND pass = :password"` is a major red flag.  No login system should be built with unencrypted passwords stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are mixing mysql and PDO which is a disaster. Mysql_ interface is deprecated use mysqli or pdo please...

2)

```
"SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = 'admin'";
```

finds only users with login admin... So you have to

```
"SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = '$login'";
```

3) $_POST variables are not safe. Users can inject malicious code...

For instance If you use mysqli then

```
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
```

To sanitize login entry and do the same for password too.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so thank you, I guess I won't ever mix those up again.

Answer (score 0):

since everybody gave advice on general issues i cut to the chase

change:

```
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $qry = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = 'admin'";
```

assuming the password ist saved to a database field named "passwort" to:

```
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        $qry = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = '".mysql_real_escape_string($login)."' and password= '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";
```

mysql_real_escape_string keeps you from beeing hacked and the database query now uses the values from the post ...

Comment: No.  `mysql_real_escape_string($password)` is a major red flag.  No login system should be built with unencrypted passwords stored in the database.  Furthermore, prepared statements should be used.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that you are mixing mysql_* functions and PDO.. the code should looks like this:

Note the prepare function which binds parameters to your SQL query - it prevents SQL injections.

```
session_start();

try {           
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stage','root','');
  }
  catch (Exception $e){ //en cas d'erreur de connexion, afficher le message           
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // username and password sent from form 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = :login AND password = :password";
    $params = array( 'login' => $login, 'password' => $pass );
    $sqlprep = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    if($sqlprep->execute($params)) {
        $count = $sqlprep->rowCount();
        if($count != 1){
            die("Incorrect login!");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
            header("location: ./login_success.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  `AND password = :password"` is a major red flag.  No login system should be built with unencrypted passwords stored in the database.