# Pass value from one php file to another php file

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I create php file for my login.....

```
<?php

//connect to the db

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user="root"; // Mysql username 
$pswd=""; // Mysql password 
$db="gpsvts_geotrack"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user_master"; // Table name

$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwd']);

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
//run the query to search for the username and password the match
$query = "SELECT uid FROM "."  ".$tbl_name. "  "."WHERE uname = '$myusername' AND passwd= '$mypassword' ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
//this is where the actual verification happens

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
//echo mysql_result($result,0);  // for correct login response
{
echo "User Found";

 }
 else  {
    echo "No Such User Found";
}


?>
```

It is just like this way...So here I select uid. I want get this uid & connect it to another php file. Really I want to get the details of the registered user by mapping so many tables. So I wrote the php file for that also. In the query inside that php file I want to equal the uid I get from above php file to the user_locator_tbl(the table in my database) uid. I did that. But I didn't think its correct. So pls help me.......

I gave here my other php file also....also I'm not fluent php...It is new to me...

```
<?php
require_once("dataget.php");
//connect to the db

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user="root"; // Mysql username 
$pswd=""; // Mysql password 
$db="gpsvts_geotrack"; // Database name 
 // Table name



$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pswd,$db);

//mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
//run the query to search for the username and password the match
//$query = "SELECT * FROM "."  ".$tbl_name. "  "."WHERE uname = '$myusername' AND passwd= '$mypassword' ";
$query = "select user_master.uid,device_locator_tbl.imei,device_locator_tbl.speed,device_locator_tbl.datetime,device_locator_tbl.number,device_master.icon 
from device_locator_tbl,device_master,device_registration,user_master where user_master.uid=device_registration.uid
 AND device_registration.imei=device_master.imei AND device_registration.imei=device_locator_tbl.imei AND user_master.uid='$query'";
//echo ($result);

$resultarray = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " );

//if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultarray))
//echo mysql_result($result,0);  // for correct login response
{
 $rows[] = $row; 
 }
 // close the database connection
mysqli_close($conn);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: create a function in the first php file and then call it from the second

Comment: @ma34 - consider making the switch to querying using PDO - you are using both mysql_ (outdated) and mysqli_ in these examples and could make your application more secure: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should use prepared statements, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated in PHP and create a real issue for SQL injection, particularly in a login.

But using your example, refer to: [PHP Login & MySql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943069/php-login-mysql-query/15943265#15943265)

The questioned code & answer there is perfectly pertinent to what you have thus far, and a simple, vastly more secure way to accomplish everything you need:

The original posters script you see is meant to store the users info into a $_SESSION[] array, from the database query like you have. Once the login attempt is validated the `header(location:)` call that you see in the original questions code will redirect the user to the location required.

Once the user is redirected, all the information from your user table query will be stored in the $_SESSION array and from then on accessible like $_SESSION[loggedinuser][userid], $_SESSION[loggedinuser][email] etc.

Remember to configure your PHP install appropriately for destroying sessions via a timeout, and also consider a logout function to destroy the user session.

So you should edit your first page like this **ONLY IF you are NOT/CANNOT switching over to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**  - remember if you use sessions you should start session on page top:

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to the db

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user="root"; // Mysql username 
$pswd=""; // Mysql password 
$db="gpsvts_geotrack"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user_master"; // Table name

$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwd']);

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
//run the query to search for the username and password the match
$query = "SELECT uid FROM "."  ".$tbl_name. "  "."WHERE uname = '$myusername' AND passwd= '$mypassword' ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
//this is where the actual verification happens

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
//echo mysql_result($result,0);  // for correct login response
{
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid'];
    header("Location: nextpage.php");
    //echo "User Found";


 }
 else  {
    echo "No Such User Found";
}


?>

And You can catch this value from next page like this: 

<?php
session_start();
// this section validate your inner files no one can enter this file without login
if(empty($_SESSION['uid'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
// now you can do whatever you like
echo $_SESSION['uid'];



require_once("dataget.php");
//connect to the db

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user="root"; // Mysql username 
$pswd=""; // Mysql password 
$db="gpsvts_geotrack"; // Database name 
 // Table name



$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pswd,$db);

//mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
//run the query to search for the username and password the match
//$query = "SELECT * FROM "."  ".$tbl_name. "  "."WHERE uname = '$myusername' AND passwd= '$mypassword' ";
$query = "select user_master.uid,device_locator_tbl.imei,device_locator_tbl.speed,device_locator_tbl.datetime,device_locator_tbl.number,device_master.icon 
from device_locator_tbl,device_master,device_registration,user_master where user_master.uid=device_registration.uid
 AND device_registration.imei=device_master.imei AND device_registration.imei=device_locator_tbl.imei AND user_master.uid='$query'";
//echo ($result);

$resultarray = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " );

//if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultarray))
//echo mysql_result($result,0);  // for correct login response
{
 $rows[] = $row; 
 }
 // close the database connection
mysqli_close($conn);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for replying..... Actually I want to do following thing... user_master.uid='$query'. here $query must be the value I get from login side php form. It must be the uid of the user when he is registered. how to do that